# Python: unnable to get any output using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** some words from any random website, but the following program is not showing errors and not showing any output when i tried printing the results.

I have checked the code twice and even incorporated an if statement to see whether the program is getting any words or not.

```py
    import requests
    import operator
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
        
    def word_count(url):

        wordlist = []

        source_code = requests.get(url)

        source = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, features="html.parser")

        for post_text in source.findAll('a', {'class':'txt'}):
            word_string=post_text.string

            if word_string is not None:
                word = word_string.lower().split()

                for each_word in word:
                    print(each_word)
                    wordlist.append(each_word)

                else:
                    print("None")
    
    word_count('https://mumbai.craigslist.org/')
```

I am expecting all the words under the "class= txt" to be displayed in the output.

Comment: Post your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OP**: *I am expecting all the words of the class text to be displayed in the output*

**The culprit**:

```
for post_text in source.findAll('a', {'class':'txt'}):
```

**The reason**:

anchor tag has no class `txt` but the span tag inside it does.

**Hence**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def word_count(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    source=BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, features="html.parser")

    for post_text in source.findAll('a'):
        s_text = post_text.find('span', class_ = "txt")
        if s_text is not None:
            print(s_text.text)

word_count('https://mumbai.craigslist.org/')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
community
activities
artists
childcare
classes
events
general
groups
local news
lost+found
missed connections
musicians
pets
.
.
.
```

Comment: Worked absolutely fine. Did you remove else statement just because you did not want None to appear for span without "class=txt"?

Comment: @Xavier Indeed, I did. but if you want to print `None`. you may!

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting the wrong elements.

if you use

```py
print(source)
```

Everything works fine but the moment you try to target the element with findAll you are targeting something wrong because you get an empty list array.

If you replace

```py
for post_text in source.findAll('a', {'class':'txt'}):
```

with

```py
for post_text in source.find_all('a'):
```

everyting seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

I have visited https://mumbai.craigslist.org/, and find there is no `<a class="txt">`, only `<span class="txt">`, so I think you can try this:

```
def word_count(url):
    wordlist = []
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    source=BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, features="html.parser")
    for post_text in source.findAll('span', {'class':'txt'}):
        word_string=post_text.text
        if word_string is not None:
            word = word_string.lower().split ()
            for each_word in word:
                print(each_word)
                wordlist.append(each_word)
         else:
            print("None")
```

it will output correctly:

```
community
activities
artists
childcare
classes
events
general
...
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the output that i got was "None". It seems the word_string holds nothing.

Comment: you should change this line too `word_string=post_text.text`